# I removed 2 of 5 links from a navbar container, and now it's no longer centered?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I got a bootstrap theme from the internet, with a navbar that has a logo image on the left side, links to pages centered in the middle, and social media account logos on the right side.  The original template had 5 links, and they were perfectly centered in the middle.  I didn't need that many so I deleted 2 of them, but now everything is off kilter.  Here is the middle part of the navbar:

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 nav-wrap">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#owl-hero" class="page-scroll">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio" class="page-scroll">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact" class="page-scroll">Contact</a></li>
        //Originally had 2 more links
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the full navbar with the above part included:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo/logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="logo"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 nav-wrap">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#owl-hero" class="page-scroll">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#portfolio" class="page-scroll">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact" class="page-scroll">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="social-media hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: What specific boostrap theme are you using?

Comment: Number 7 on [this](https://almsaeedstudio.com/blog/10-Free-Responsive-Bootstrap-Templates-For-2016) list

Comment: any demo to check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just reduce the size for col-md and offset the menu :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo/logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="logo"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4 col-xs-12 nav-wrap">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#owl-hero" class="page-scroll">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#portfolio" class="page-scroll">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact" class="page-scroll">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="social-media hidden-sm hidden-xs">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works pretty well! I did change it to `col-md-8 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-12 nav-wrap` as that seems to work better.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The CSS classes `col-md-8 col-xs-12 nav-wrap` are probably the ones determining the width of that part of the navigation bar. Look in your CSS file to see if you can reduce the width of one or more of those classes.

Answer (score 0):

try adding 2 blank line items like this:

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 nav-wrap">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#owl-hero" class="page-scroll">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio" class="page-scroll">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact" class="page-scroll">Contact</a></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Surprisingly that doesn't work, it's still off center which might mean I have to reconsider the problem